# Relating certain terms of a QR factorization and a Cholesky factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let A be an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $n$. Let 
$$A = Q \begin{bmatrix}R\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
be the QR factorization of A, with $Q$ orthogonal and $R$ an $n\times n$ upper triangular matrix. Let $A^TA=LL^T$ be the Cholesky factorization of $A^TA$.

(a) Show that $R^TR=LL^T$. 
(b) Can one conclude that $R=L^T$, if not, give a counterexample.

I have proved the first one, but I cannot show the (b). Is the Cholesky factorization unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be SPD. Then $A$ has the unique lower triangular Cholesky factor $L$ with positive diagonal entries.

**Slightly longer but complete proof:** I'm not going to show that the Cholesky factorisation exists and take that as done. To prove the uniqueness, we can proceed by induction. The statement is trivial for $n=1$, so assume that it is true for SPD matrices of the dimension $n-1$. Let $L$ be the Cholesky factor of $A$ with positive diagonal entries and assume that there is another such Cholesky factor $\tilde{L}$. Partition all these matrices as
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21}^T & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
L=\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & 0 \\ l_{21}^T & l_{22}
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
\tilde{L}=\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{L}_{11} & 0 \\ \tilde{l}_{21}^T & \tilde{l}_{22}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the blocks $A_{11}$, $L_{11}$, and $\tilde{L}_{11}$ are $(n-1)\times(n-1)$.
Since $A=L_{11}L_{11}^T=\tilde{L}_{11}\tilde{L}_{11}^T$ are two Cholesky factorisations of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ SPD matrix $A_{11}$ (with positive diagonal), we have $\color{red}{\tilde{L}_{11}=L_{11}}$ from the induction assumption.
Hence we have that
$$
\tilde{L}=\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & 0 \\ \tilde{l}_{21}^T & \tilde{l}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and it remains to show that if $l_{22}$ and $\tilde{l}_{22}$ are positive, then $\tilde{l}_{21}=l_{21}$ and $\tilde{l}_{22}=l_{22}$.
Since $LL^T=\tilde{L}\tilde{L}^T$, we have that $\hat{L}^T\hat{L}=I$ with $\hat{L}=\tilde{L}^{-1}L$.
We can compute the matrix $\hat{L}$ "explicitly" in the block form as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
\hat{L}&=\tilde{L}^{-1}L
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & 0 \\ \tilde{l}_{21}^T & \tilde{l}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & 0 \\ l_{21}^T & l_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\ -\tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}\tilde{l}_{21}^TL_{11}^{-1} & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & 0 \\ l_{21}^T & l_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21})^T & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}l_{22}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{split}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
I&=\hat{L}\hat{L}^T
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\ \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21})^T & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}l_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21}) \\ 0 & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}l_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
I & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21}) \\
\tilde{l}_{22}^{-1}(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21})^T & \tilde{l}_{22}^{-2}(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21})^T(l_{21}-\tilde{l}_{21})+\tilde{l}_{22}^{-2}l_{22}^2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{split}
$$
Since the (2,1) and (1,2) block entries must be zero (the matrix on the right-hand side must be equal to the identity) and $\tilde{l}_{22}\neq 0$, we have $\color{red}{\tilde{l}_{21}=l_{21}}$. So what remains from the bottom-right entry of $\hat{L}\hat{L}^T$ is $\tilde{l}_{22}^{-2}l_{22}^2$ and this must be equal to 1. Because  $\tilde{l}_{22}>0$ and $l_{22}>0$, we get
$$
\tilde{l}_{22}^{-2}l_{22}^2=1\Leftrightarrow
\tilde{l}_{22}^2=l_{22}^2\Leftrightarrow
\color{red}{\tilde{l}_{22}=l_{22}}.
$$
Therefore, $\color{blue}{\tilde{L}=L}$. Q.E.D.

---

To illustrate that the positivity of the diagonal of $L$ is a necessary condition for the uniqueness, consider the following example:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
L=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
\tilde{L}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Both $L$ and $\tilde{L}$ are Cholesky factors of $A$. However, $L$ is the *only* Cholesky factor of $A$ with positive diagonal entries.

Comment: So you mean the Cholesky factorization is unique if and only if the diagonal entries are zero, right?  But how about the (b), is it right?

Comment: No I haven't said that. The Cholesky factors with *positive diagonal* entries are unique. I'll give an example that this is necessary in an edit.

Comment: So the (b) is wrong under the condition that the diagonal entries of Cholesky factors are not all positive?

Comment: I'm not sure that (b) can be correct or wrong. It essentially asks whether "it is like $\color{red}{\text{this}}$" or "it is like $\color{blue}{\text{that}}$" and the answer depends on how the Cholesky factor is defined (constructed). Usual implementations of this factorisation force positive diagonal entries and hence always give the unique factor. If this is not ensured, then no, they are not unique.